# Are centrifugal fans subject to triboelectric effects, and if so can the increase in charge be predicted and measured?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, electricity

A centrifugal blower is a device that moves gas, usually under power of an electric motor. The blower housing and impeller may be metallic, but often are made of plastic materials. My question is threefold.

1. Can a centrifugal blower, if made from plastics impart an electric charge on the outlet gas?
2. If so what is the predicted increase/decrease in charge based on assumptions of materials, geometry of construction, fan speed, etc. using fundamental physical laws?
3. Is there an instrument that can accurately measure the charge of a stream of gas flow?